# Comment rendering bug with inline code

Tags: bug, comments, markdown-rendering

I just encountered [this beauty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50137389/11942268):

[image]

It looks like inline code does not get rendered properly in the comments by not breaking succeeding spaces or some sort of escaping problem.